# Gradle publish to different mavenLocal

Tags: maven, gradle

I want to build and publish gradle artifacts with `gradle install` to a local maven repository. Normally we would use:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

However that would publish the artifacts to the general user's `.m2`. I need to override the `.m2` so that I can run jobs in parallel and cache their results.

```
repositories {
    maven(url = System.getenv("mavenLocal"))
}
```

Once set like this, it uses the repo ONLY for the input, but not for the output and the build artifacts still go to `~/.m2`. Is there a way to force `mavenLocal()` use different directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repositories` is for dependencies only.

to control where the artefacts are published you need to add `publishing`

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            url = "$buildDir/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories

Comment: Thanks! I guess now I should use `gradle publishToMavenLocal`? However it still publishes to `~/.m2` with no error :/

Comment: use `publish` - this uses your build/repo path,   the `publishToMavenLocal.disable = true` publishes to the system maven dir